# Cannot remove English (Singapore) keyboard from language bar on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language

Recently I noticed that I have 2 English keyboards on the language bar.
However when I checked the installed services, there's only "English (US)" available.

I tried to add "English (Singapore)" and re-remove it, but when I logged off and logged back in, "English (Singapore)" appeared back again.

I know it doesn't really affect me in anyway since both of the keyboards are in English, but it's rather strange that "English (Singapore)" is appearing while not listed in installed services..

[image: Image2]
[image: Image1]

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you (or was the computer) in Singapore? And was a localized version of Windows installed?

Comment: Yes, the PC is based on Singapore .

Comment: Seems I read somewhere else that the settings for the OS installation language cannot be removed, even if not set in Region and Language settings.

Comment: Thank you for the input user3169, but it seems like a user profile issue , I tried to login to another PC , it is still showing English (Singapore) and English (US).  But when another user logged in to the same PC , it only shows English (US).

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the language (english Singapore),  apply, then remove it. Then put the computer in safe mode.

If it doesn't back again. There should be something wrong with startup program.

If still, try to repeat steps above in safe mode, then restart (in safe mode).

Comment: this should be accepted answer, it worked for me